# How can you show the first cell in a cluster in Excel? And how can you lookup the value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Several questions. But let me break down the problem of what I am trying to do:

1. I have a condition to show YES/NO if a certain value is met. If YES >= 60 and NO <=30 - this is easy I can do this
2. It usually generates several consecutive rows or "clusters". I want to show the first row in the group of YES. How can I do this in that grouping? (see condition 2 in image)
3. Same thing but for NO (see condition 3).
4. From there, I want to look up the value at NO (value 1 from the image, which is 0.13) and look for the last (or "first" from the group) YES (which value = 0.123 and take the difference. How can I do this? This should be A9 - A3.
5. Repeat for as long as it goes.

[image: Image of Excel sheet of above in cells]

Comment: Can you please clarify step 4? I understand `A3` corresponds to the first `YES` in a cluster of `YES`es. But why `A11`? Also, what happens if there's a third cluster of `YES`es?

Comment: Whoops, let me change it (EDITS made). I deleted a few cells to make the image easier. It should be A9-A3. The idea is to take the value when the condition is first YES and first NO and take the difference of the value at those conditions.

Comment: A bit more data may be helpful, what `YES` value would be substracted from the next `NO` value? A larger data sample with expected results may be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach, producing the same output which you need.

[image]

- Formula in column C (tracking first YES per group): `=IF(IFERROR(VALUE(C1),0)>0,IF(D2>0,0,C1),IF(B2>=60,ROW(),0))`
- Formula in column D (to track first NO per group): `=IF(IFERROR(VALUE(C1),0)>0,IF(IFERROR(VALUE(D1),0)>0,D1,IF(B2<=30,ROW(),0)),0)`
- Formula in Column E (calculating difference): `=IF(AND(D2>0,IFERROR(VALUE(C1),0)>0),OFFSET($A$1,C1-1,0)-OFFSET($A$1,D2-1,0),"")`

If you need exactly the same columns, you can hide columns C & D and easily create new ones with YES & NO.